# Android : Remove titlebar / go fullscreen while in EDITING MODE in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

I have **successfully removed** title bar and also notification bar from android using this code in styles

```
<style name="NoAction"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
```

it works properly while running the app but not while in IDE i.e the preview of the design that is going to be the final output still shows the ActionBar & NotificationBar

[image: editor screenshot]

didn't found any solutions yet for realtime INEDIT mode changes,
pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your XML layout and Select Design mode. Find App Theme button below opened image tabs.

See image below.

[image]